# Django: How to change the key of the dict generated by annotated query?

Tags: python, django, orm, django-queryset

I have the following query:

```
cc = Comment.objects.filter(pk__in=cids).values('user_id').annotate(z=Count('user_id')).order_by('user_id')
print cc
```

The result currently looks something like this:

```
[{'z': 1, 'user_id': 2L}, {'z': 2, 'user_id': 4L}, {'z': 2, 'user_id': 38L}]
```

However, what I am trying to obtain something like this:

```
[{'user_id': 2L, 'z':1}, {'user_id': 4L,'z': 2, }, { 'user_id': 38L},'z': 2]
```

I understand there are workarounds like
converting valuequeryset to dict -> reverse dict, to get the above result. But is there any way to get this through query?

Answer (score 0):

dictionary in Python is unordered, what you just see like `z` before `user_id` is just coincidence.

if you want a ordered dict, try to use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) for Python2.7 and higher version.

Comment: Thank you for you advice Sinux. I realised what I actually want to have was a dictionary, so I went ahead and used this for my project. rel = {c['user_id']: c['z'] for c in cc}. Just in case anyone needed this.